# Waiting on a list of futures VS Waiting on individual futures

Tags: scala, future

I am trying to understand the pros and cons - if any - of the following two approaches

```
  def doSomething(): Future[Unit] = ???
  
  // Create one big list of futures and wait on this future
  private val oneBigFuture: Future[immutable.IndexedSeq[Unit]] = Future.sequence {
    (1 to 1000).map(_ => doSomething)
  }

  Await.result(oneBigFuture, 10.seconds)

  // Wait on the individual futures created by the doSomething() method
  (1 to 1000).foreach {
    _ =>
      val individualFuture = doSomething()
      Await.result(individualFuture, 10.seconds)
  }
```

What is the benefit of creating one big list of futures and submitting this to the `result` method instead of submitting the individual `Future`s produced by the `doSomething()` method to the `result` method?

Obviously the first approach creates a batch operation but I am not sure if the compiler converts the second approach into a batch operation as well - since it's wrapped around a `foreach` statement.

Comment: Neither is a batch operation, the compiler won't do anything, and awaiting is a bad practice. You should use the one that makes more sense for your program, usually that would be that it is easier to manipulate a future of a list with all the results than a list of futures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach should be much faster because all the `Future`s are started before blocking occurs, whilst in the second approach blocking occurs before each next `Future` starts. You can test this like so

```
def doSomething(): Future[Unit] = Future { Thread.sleep(1000); println(1) }
```

where

```
Await.result(Future.sequence((1 to 10).map(_ => doSomething())), Duration.Inf)
```

would take about a second, whilst

```
(1 to 10).foreach(_ => Await.result(doSomething(), Duration.Inf))
```

would take about 10 seconds.